# Solve $xuu_x+yuu_y=u^2-1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$
\begin{cases}
xuu_x+yuu_y=u^2-1,x>0\\
u(x,x^2)=x^3\\
\end{cases}
$$

b. Is there a single solution when $-\infty<x<\infty$

$$\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{dy}{yu}=\frac{du}{u^2-1}$$

$$\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{dy}{yu}\Rightarrow \frac{x}{y}=c_1=\phi_1 \qquad (1)$$

$$\frac{dx}{xu}=\frac{du}{u^2-1}\Rightarrow\frac{x^2}{u^2-1}=c_2=\phi_2 ,(u\neq \pm 1) \qquad (2)$$

So $$F \left(\frac{x}{y} \right)=\frac{x^2}{u^2-1}$$

Using initial condition:

$$F \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{x^2}{x^6-1}$$

Set $x=\frac{1}{t}:$

$$F(t)=\frac{\frac{1}{t^2}}{\frac{1}{t^6}-1}\Rightarrow F(t)=\frac{t^4}{1-t^6}$$

So
$$F\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)=\frac{\frac{x^4}{y^4}}{1-\frac{x^6}{y^6}}\Rightarrow F\left(\frac{x}{y} \right)=\frac{x^4y^2}{y^6-x^6}$$

So
$$\frac{x^2}{u^2-1}=\frac{x^4y^2}{y^6-x^6}\Rightarrow u^2=\frac{y^6-x^6}{x^2y^2}+1$$

How to approach b.?

Comment: What happens when $(y^6 - x^6)/(x^2 y^2) + 1 < 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael either $x^2y^2<0$ or $y^6-x^6<0$ ?

Comment: Well, $x^2 y^2 < 0$ isn't going to happen if your variables are real, but the other one...  What does that say about $u$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael if $|y^6-x^6|>x^2y^2$ then $u^2<0$ else $u^2>0$?